# Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable nonnegative integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Then for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there exists a set $E\in\ \Sigma$ such that $\mu(E) \lt \infty$ and

$$\int_X {f}\,{d\mu} \leq \int_{E} {f}{\,d\mu} + \varepsilon$$

**My attempt:**

I called $E_n= f^{-1}((-\infty,n))$

Each $E_n$ is measurable since f is a measurable function.

We have: $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ and  $\bigcup{E_n}=X$.

Since $\lambda(A) = \int_{A}{f}\,{d\mu}$ is a measure, by continuity of $\lambda$, we have:

$$\int_{E_n}{f}{d\mu} \to \int_{X}{f}{d\mu}$$

Thus, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $n_0$ such that
 $n\gt n_0 \Longrightarrow   \int_{X}{f}\,{d\mu} - \int_{E_n}{f}\,{d\mu} \lt \varepsilon$. Then I took $E = E_{n_0}$.

I'm having trouble with $\mu(E) \lt \infty$.

Can anyone help me finish the argument?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your $E_n=f^{-1}((-\infty,-1/n)\cup(1/n,\infty))$. Now all of your arguments still work except now $\cup E_n=X\setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ which causes no problems.

However, now you know $m(E_n)$ is finite for all $n$, otherwise $\infty>\int_{X}|f|d\mu\geq \int_{E_n} \dfrac{1}{n}=\infty$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why doesn't $\bigcup{E_n} = X\cap (f^{-1}(0)^c $ cause any problems ?

Comment: Because $\int_{f^{-1}(0)}f=0$. So your integral over $E_n$ approaches integral over $\cup E_n$ which is just equal to the integral over $X$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you @Konrad Wrobel for your explanations

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but a preliminary step will ensure that $E$ as finite measure. First choose $l\in(0,1)$ so small that $\int_{f^{-1}[0,l)}f\,d\nu<\epsilon/2$. Now consider $E_n=\{x:l\le f(x)<n\}$, and argue as you have done.